# Task.Wait() never returns when called during initialization of static field?

Tags: c#, task

I have the following simple code:

```
    class Program
    {
        public static readonly List<int> Years = BuildList();

        static void Main(string[] args) { }

        private static List<int> BuildList()
        {
            var t = Task.Run(() => x());
            t.Wait();
            return new List<int>();
        }

        private static void x()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
```

After debugging, `x()` is never entered and `t.Wait()` never completes / returns and hangs forever. Can anyone explain this bizarre behavior?

It's not like there are any UI blocking calls, all I can guess is that the threadpool is somehow maxed out?

If I remove the `.Wait()` call, then `x()` does eventually get entered.

Note that calling `BuildList()` from `Main` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Needz moar info

Comment: This unquestionably isn't what you're actually doing, if that's what you're seeing.  You need to provide an example that is actually capable of reproducing your issue.  Additionally, you should never use the `Task` constructor, ever.  Use `Task.Run` if you want to start a new `Task` that represents doing work in a thread pool thread.

Comment: "It's not like there are any UI blocking calls"... `t.Wait` _is_ blocking your main thread. And `t.Start()` only schedules the task, it does not use another thread for that.

Comment: @Servy ` var t = Task.Run(() => x()); t.Wait();` produces the exact same behaviour

Comment: @maxp Again, you have not provided enough information to reproduce your problem.  If you were actually running the code shown, it would work.  Using `Task.Run` wasn't the cause of your problem, just a tangential best practice.

Comment: Apart from the request to post an actual reproducible example, why did you even try `.Start()`? **All** examples use `Task.Run` or `TaskFactory.StartNew` and all related SO questions get the same warning you got as the very first comment. No tutorial or programming guide mentions `Task.Start`. Where did you find this method and why did you use it?

Comment: Also, don't look for ThreadPool saturation or bugs. Your code is essentially a noop and the threadpool can grow to many thousands of threads

Comment: @Servy updated with full code

Comment: @Servy *static* field, static initialization. The OP is probably running into an *initialization* issue caused by the use of static fields

Comment: @Servy BuildList() is called on the `Years` declaration...

Comment: @maxp you are playing with the *type's initialization*. You are blocking the construction of your own class that the *static* field can't be initialized. Without that, you can't call the static method.

Comment: @maxp please don't use such contrived examples next time. Also, before assuming that the framework is broken, consider that it may be your own code that is at fault. The relevant programmer's proverb is "Think horses not zebras". I think it's Joel Spolsky's

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: it's from a medical professor in the 1940s, apparently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_(medicine)

Comment: @JacobKrall Spolsky invented time travel? I'll be ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inside the static initializer for `Program` you're starting a new thread and having it call a method on the class *that you are currently running the static initializer for*.  C# will ensure that a class is initialized exactly once, so if two threads try to initialize a class then one will wait for the other to finish.  Since the initializer is waiting for `x` to finish before it can continue, and `x` is waiting for the initializer to finish before it can run, you have a deadlock.

Comment: Subtle but awesome.  I like the explanation.  Something to remember.